# Parsing an Extra String to Check For Data

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing

I have an extra which will be passed to my service as an extra and I need to check to see if it contains specific data but I'm not sure exactly how this is accomplished so I could use a hand in learning how to accomplish this.

Extra Format:

```
USI;1; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747
```

The value I'm looking for is the 1 just after USI - to find out if it contains a 1 or a zero

Comment: Do you always want to check the second item? Or it's the item right after USI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested, works as it should.

```
 String text = "USI;0; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747";
        if(text.contains("USI;1;"))
        {
            System.out.println("It contains!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("There isn't one :(");
        }
```

Comment: This might not be safe if USI can change. OP does not specify but better play it safe and use split.

Comment: Uh, that's true. I just assumed it

Comment: US1 actually doesn't change - thank you everyone for your help!

- Amani Swann

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to do it

Edit: Fixed the compilation issue :)

```
String str = "USI;1; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747";

String[] carr = str.split(";");

if("1".equals(carr[1])){
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: `String[] carr = str.split(";");if("1".equals(carr[1])){/*Do something*/};`

Answer (score 0):

just put your extra format in String variable like below:

```
String str = "USI;1; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747";
for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++)
    if(string.charAt(i) == '1'){
     // what ever you want here when it match.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int flag = Integer.parseInt(yourString.split(";")[1]);

if (flag  == 0) {
     //handle it
}else if (flag ==1){

}
```